# Invariant Violation: AnimatedValueXY must be initialized with an object of numbers or AnimatedValues

Tags: react-native, expo, react-animated

```js
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { View, StyleSheet, Animated } from 'react-native';

export default class Ball extends Component {
  componentWillMount(){
    this.position = new Animated.ValueXY(0,0);
    Animated.spring(this.position, {
      toValue: {x :200, y: 500}
    }).start();
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <Animated.View style={this.position.getLayout()}>
        <View style={styles.ball} />
      </Animated.View>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  ball: {
    height: 60,
    width: 60,
    borderRadius: 30,
    borderWidth: 30,
    borderColor: 'green'
  }
});
```

[image]

The code as attached in image above has no problem running if `Animated.ValueXY(100,100)` being changed to `Animated.ValueXY(0,0)`

Can anyone care to explain why such behaviour exist as my idea is instead of having this ball to start moving from `x:0,y:0` i would like it to start moving from `x:100,y:100` instead

Answer (score 5):

```
this.position = new Animated.ValueXY({ x: 100, y: 100 });
```

Try this